# Emacsclient keep buffers after closing

Tags: emacs, emacsclient

In emacsclient, is there a way to open a file from the command line such that its buffer will remain open on the server after I close the client?

Alternatively, is there a command I can run from in a client to tell it to effectively detach from a buffer, so that the buffer does not get killed when the client exits?

Normally when closing emacsclient either with `C-x C-c` or `C-x #`, the buffer(s) associated with that client get killed, which is usually convenient behavior, but sometimes I would like for buffers to stay alive after closing. So far the only way I have found to accomplish this is to run the client without specifying any files, then visit them with `C-x C-f`, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, one option is to use emacsclient's eval command line option to run a lisp command to find the file you want.

`emacsclient -c -e '(find-file "my_file")'`

Obviously this is a lot more to type than the command sequence `emacsclient -c`, `C-x C-f`, `my_file`, but it could pretty easily be wrapped in a script that takes an extra argument to tell it whether to just choose the file or use `find-file`.

Someone more well versed in elisp than I could probably just add the option directly into emacs.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this by using the `-n` option. That means that it won't wait for you to "finish" the buffer and it'll just stay in the buffer list. I use this with emacsclient myself.

Comment: This causes it to open in an existing client if I already have one open. I still want it to open in the terminal that I'm actually in.

Comment: Oh, I think you need -t for that. HTH

Comment: `-t` retains the problem of buffers dying when I close the client. `-t` and `-n` are mutually exclusive, but each has *some* of the properties I want. I want creating new frames from `-t` and detachable buffers from `-n`.

Comment: `M-x report-emacs-bug` ? You can use `-n -c` with GUI Emacs, so I would expect to be able to use `-n -t` with terminal Emacs.

Answer (score 1):

According the info manual, if you *never* want to kill emacsclient buffers, when you're done with them, you can customise the `server-kill-new-buffers` variable (more information at `C-h v server-kill-new-buffers`).

For you use-case, depending on how often you want the buffers killed or not, you could set the above variable to `nil` and then manually kill the buffers that you *do* want killed.